# Readable, Nested PHP Loops/Ifs in HTML

Tags: php, html

I am trying to separate my PHP and HTML. I am passing an array of PHP variables to my HTML code. I am creating a select dropdown and trying to select a specific option based on my variables. Like this:

```
//example vars from PHP array (uses magic getter and accessed by $this->varName)
//$array = array('aaa' => '123', 'bbb' => '456', 'ccc' => '789');
//$selected = 'bbb';

<select name="name" id="id">
<option value="0">Choose n Option</option>
<?
foreach($this->array as $key => $value)
{
    ?>
    //$selected may not be set
    <option value="<?=$key?>" <? echo isset($this->selected) ? (strcmp($key,$this->selected)==0 ? 'selected' : '') : '' ?> ><?=$value?></option>
    <?
}
?>
</select>
```

The outcome is:

```
<select name="name" id="id">
    <option value="0">Choose an Option</option>
    <option value="aaa"  >123</option>
    <option value="bbb" selected >456</option> //'selected' determined by code above
    <option value="ccc"  >789</option>
</select>
```

Is there a better to way write which option should be selected? Either using PHP or changing my logic? `<? echo isset($this->selected) ? (strcmp($key,$this->selected)==0 ? 'selected' : '') : '' ?>` does not seem very readable. I would like to know if there is better way to write code in situations where the HTML/view code needs to use nested loops and ifs, especially when inside an HTML tag like this case.

I thought about putting the result of `<? echo isset($this->selected) ? (strcmp($key,$this->selected)==0 ? 'selected' : '') : '' ?>` into a variable and then I would just have

```
$newSelectVar = <? echo isset($this->selected) ? (strcmp($key,$this->selected)==0 ? 'selected' : '') : '' ?>;
<option value="<?=$key?>" <?=$newSelectVar?> ><?=$value?></option>
```

I didn't want to do this because I was trying to only use inline PHP (I read this makes the HTML more readable and maintainable), but I guess I am already breaking that rule with the `foreach`.

Comment: when writing HTML using loops I often append all the HTML code to a variable and echo it at the end. For the `selected` variable, instead of using true or false, put `selected` or nothing, then always use the variable (1 if less)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people will start screaming at you to use a templating system... but since PHP **IS** a templating system, that's redundant. Instead of breaking out of PHP mode to output a few chars of text, try something more like:

```
foreach($this->array as $key => $value)
   $sel = isset($this->selected) ? (strcmp($key,$this->selected)==0 ? 'selected' : '') : '';
   echo <<<EOL
<option value="{$key}" {$sel}>{$value}></option>
EOL;
}
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me. So the advice I read that said "only use inline PHP in HTML" shouldn't be used in this case?

Comment: it all comes down to just how much php you're embedding. a simple `<?= $var ?>` is no problem. But if you're embedding complicated logic (and especially nested ternaries), then you're better off using something else, like an intermediate variable.

Answer (score 1):

**You should never bind** your business logic and presentation layer (*HTML template* in this case). All what you're doing now already breaks [SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Well, in order to keep this thing more maintainable you need something like *HTML Helper class*. This avoids any kind of logic within presentation.

```
class HTMLHelper
{
   public static function isSelected($actual, $expected)
   {
       if ($actual === $expected){
           print 'selected="selected"';
       }
   }

   public static function isChecked()
   {
      // The same goes for checkbox, but you want
      // checked="checked" instead of selected="selected" here
   }
}
```

**Note**: You should use a full alternate for templates that dedicated for them and only, not `<?php { ... ?>`

Then in your presentation

```
<select>

<?php foreach($this->array as $key => $value) : ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $key;?>" <?php HTMLHelper::isSelected($this->selected, $key);?> ><?php echo $value; ?></option>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</select>
```

The major benefits you get are:

1) Modularity. The same `HTMLHelper::isSelected` could be used for another templates as well.

2) [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

3) Code becomes easy to maintain

Comment: This alternative syntax is new to me and looks like a great idea.

Comment: One more thing. `<?php if (something){ ?> <html here> <?php }; ?>`. This syntax works as well. I like this since it keeps the brackets. Is this okay as well?

Comment: The alternative syntax **should** only be used within templates. Yep, standard syntax works as well, (I didn't say it doesn't), but you'd better avoid this. So, more appropriate syntax for templates would be `<?php if (..) : ?>..html stuff here..<?php endif; ?>` the same goes for : `foreach/endforeach`, `while/endwhile`

Comment: Ha, I usually separate the bracket onto a new line so initially it looked like an alternative-alternative syntax. Oops, obviously just standard syntax. Why should I avoid this (in templates)? It still seems to be inline PHP.

Comment: You should avoid default syntax in templates(`<?php { `) because: 1) Alternate syntax makes your logic more template-specific. 2) The alternate syntax has been dedicated for templates since the beginning (Again: Alternate syntax is not for classes or whole php scripts, but for templates only). Don't ask me why - just start using it, and you would feel the difference :)

Comment: And also, `<?php if () { ?> html stuff <?php } ?>` works as well(as you said before), but its just ugly. `<?php if () : ?>html stuff<?php endif; ?>` is more cleaner and maintainable.